# Guides to help learn C++ specifically from a C# background

Tags: c#, c++

Is there a guide/reference anyone would recommend to pick up C++ *specifically* if you have strong experience of C#?

There are C++ guides, but a lot start with the absolute basics and I feel I've covered a lot with my C# learnings.

But the absolute basics may be a good thing and I may be barking up the wrong tree - I imagine some people might say "you should just consider it completely different and learn it separately otherwise you'll miss bits"

I actually used to be "fairly OK" at C++, but it's all gone...

Comment: Please check out all the "learn c++" questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learn+c%2B%2B

Comment: I'd had a look through actually but wasn't sure if there was anything specific for C# peeps playing to our way of thinking!

Comment: The only question I can see that looks particularly similar is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347/what-is-the-best-way-to-go-from-java-c-to-c. Nonetheless, I think is a good question, so I'd like to see it stay open for some more info.

Comment: Duplicate: How to learn C++ as a C# programmer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607301/how-to-learn-c-as-a-c-programmer

Comment: Actually one of those links points again to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531722/c-for-the-c-programmer

But I did look and I didn't find them!

I appreciate it is a duplicate question now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful info on a C# to C++ (Win32) project port.  Might be a good starting point.

http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/03/index.html